# Нужна ли запятая после слова "смерти" ?

Tags: пунктуация

"Фильм о любви до самой смерти вопреки всему".

Answer (score 1):

После "смерти вопреки всему" никакие запятые уже не помогут.
Переделывайте фразу.

Answer (score 1):

А если серьезно, то по этому поводу есть конкретное правило: дополнения с предлогами вопреки, согласно, в связи с  и т.п. обособляются, если значительно распространены. В данном случае этого нет, поэтому запятая не нужна

Comment: Если серьезно, то лучше в данном случае не вспоминать про правила.

Answer (score 0):

[[@виктор1799](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799)](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799), а можно пример, где дополнения с предлогами вопреки, согласно, в связи с и т.п. обособляются, если значительно распространены? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: В маленькой комнатушке под крышей он дни и ночи проводит над книгами, голодает, холодает и, как Горький у нас, вопреки всему, упрямо карабкается к вершинам знаний. [Б. Н. Полевой. Несколько слов о Джеке Лондоне (1970-1981)] [омонимия снята] ←…→

... 

Ей нравились девушки-сезонницы, работницы в тяжёлых цехах, военные регулировщицы, которые, живя в бараках, работая в пыли, грязи, накручивали перманент, гляделись в зеркальце, пудрили облупившиеся носы; упрямые птицы в непогоду, вопреки всему, пели свою птичью песню. [Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 3 (1960)] [омонимия снята] ←…→

Comment: (нац корпус). Там их еще много.

PS Наскольок понимаю речь идет о рапространённости всего предложения, не самого дополнения.